# Capturing network traffic using wireshark

Tags: lan, wireshark

I have 15 systems connected with same LAN. I want to capture all the data packets(network-traffic) through every system from my single PC connected with same LAN using wireshark.Can anybody plz help me?

Comment: We can't teach you how to use WireShark, that is a big subject. What, specifically, do you need help with.

Answer (score 2):

Buddy, Wireshark only shows capture traffic in a readable way for the user, this is the only function, read, decrypt, follow networks streams, and so on. What you want to do is configure some kind of mirror of all your pcs to yours. I guess, you need to read the documentation of your switch, and  it mirror capabilities. By the other hand, there is one kind of wireshark configuration that gives you what you want, but you need to install wireshark on every pc, and activate the remote capture on it.